# How do I show continuity of mixed-weak solution to Zaremba's problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, finite-element-method, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

I am interested in showing continuity/boundedness of the solution to the following problem pde:

\begin{align*}
0 &= \mathbf{q} + \mathbf{\nabla}u && \quad x\in \Omega,\\
0 &= \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot q && \quad x\in \Omega,\\
0 &= u && \quad x\in \partial \Omega_D,\\
g &= \mathbf{q}\cdot \mathbf{\eta} &&\quad x\in \partial\Omega_N.
\end{align*}

How can I show that the norm to the weak solution to this problem is bounded by the Neumann Data?  In other words, How can I show there exists a $C$ dependent only on the domain so that

$$
\| \mathbf{q}\|_{H^{\mathrm{div}}(\Omega)} \le C \| g \|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega_N)} 
$$

I would especially appreciate references to papers or books.  If this is handled in any of the standard references (Grisvard, or Gilbarg and Trudinger) or the like, and I have missed it, could you tell me specifically where this is handled?